# c# moving picturebox using timer and stop it in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, picturebox, dice

I'm making a game, snakes and ladders and I want to add a timer on my player so it can move with slow speed. And stop it after moving the blocks.

Code is given below

```
namespace Snakes_Ladders {
  public partial class Form2: Form {
    bool red = false;
    int x = 0, y = 442, dicevalue;
    public Form2() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Application.Exit();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      pictureBox4.Left += 2;

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      timer1.Start();
      this.Hide();
      pictureBox4.Visible = false;
      pictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile(@ "C:\Users\pasha\source\repos\Snakes Ladders\Snakes Ladders\Resources\dice.png");
      pictureBox3.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      dicevalue = AddLogics.rolldice(pictureBox3);
      label2.Text = dicevalue.ToString(); //Open Dice First time...

      if (label2.Text == "6" && red == false) {
        pictureBox4.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        red = true;
        pictureBox4.Location = new Point(x, y);
        label4.Text = x.ToString();
        label6.Text = y.ToString();
      }

      if (red == true) {
        x += 70;
        pictureBox4.Location = new Point(x, y);
        label4.Text = x.ToString();
        label6.Text = y.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

while I also used a class which is given below.

```
namespace Snakes_Ladders {
  class AddLogics {
    public static int rolldice(PictureBox px) // Roll Dice mathod...
    {
      int dice = 0;
      Random r = new Random();
      dice = r.Next(1, 7);

      px.Image = Image.FromFile(@ "C:\Users\pasha\source\repos\Snakes Ladders\Snakes Ladders\Resources\" + dice + ".png ");
        px.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        return dice;
      }
    }
  }
```

I wanted to move my picturebox while timer, and it should stop right after moving the numbers shown in dice.

Comment: What did u try? Why didnt it work? What exactly is your Problem ? This Platform is not meant to Fix your work/problem because u are "lazy" to research it. Provide us with information on what you tried/ your research/ why it did not work. Read [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as you see (it wasnt me) your Post will just get DownVotes and ultimately will be closed if ur Problem isnt properly Documentated

Answer (score 0):

What Exactly is `pictureBox4.Left += 2` doing? You probably wanna do

`pictureBox4.Location = new Point(pictureBox4.Location.x + 2, pictureBox4.Location.y)`

this will set your pictureBox4 2 pixels to the Right(or left i dont remember).

As you are Starting the Timer (you dont show how you create the Timer a reference to it for the Intervall would be usefull as its monumental to the Timer) if the Timer ticks your PictureBox will be moved..

**Some additional Tipps.**

Your Code is very hard to Read i see that you are new, as we all once were.
So just the next time you code think of these things... it will help yourself more than you can think of:

**Name your Variables / Methods accordingly**

pictureBox4.. is exactly what? name it, if u are creating it in the Designer there is a Properties window, where you can change the Name. so you have a meaningfull way of referencing it in your Code. Your whole code is full of Label1...2...3.. PictureBox1...2..3. Just so you will realize it yourself, check your code 2 days after you Programm it... Can you realy say which label is which? It helps trust me.

**(Almost) Never hardcode your Objects (atleast in your Project)**

You will face an Easy Problem, as you are Programming a Game i can think of pictureBox4 as a Player... What if there are 2 Players? with ur Method you will only Move the pictureBox4 or all if you think of writing them in there.. As example for this Project.. make a method which returns you a pictureBox of the CurrentPlayer, so you always just have to think for 1 Player, just at the end of the Turn switch the Player and *boom* your Program will (almost certainly) look much more Professional and it will be easier to work Step by Step.

Sry for this wall of Text, this just reminded me of my own start in Programming, but TLDR Programming is one of these things, which *WILL* do imense Fun if u are Structured and follow some Rules. Because the only one getting hurt by "bad" code is urself (or your Team in which u work) u will get stressed and lose motivation. Keep it Clean, Keep it Flexible.

PS: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) next time before you ask a Question.. Good Luck !